# adding firefox image to the subuser

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, docker

I followed all the steps to create subuser given on subuser.org

I am not able to create firefox image and not able to restrict the access to the Downloads folder as given in the video and documentation

Please provide me with the solution. i need it for my project

Comment: provide the link followed for creating subuser and adding firefox

Comment: https://github.com/subuser-security/subuser

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZrs8KngN68

Answer (score 0):

You would create a folder my-subuser-images and then create a second folder firefox in the first one:

my-subuser-images/firefox

In the firefox folder, you need to create yet another sub-folder: docker-image

Once you have done that you need to create two files:

```
permissions.json
```

And

```
docker-image/SubuserImagefile
```

Your file layout should look like the one found at the subuser-default-repository

In the permissions.json file, you tell subuser what Firefox is allowed to do:

```
{"description":"A popular web browser."
,"maintainer":"student"
,"executable":"/usr/bin/firefox"
,"gui":{"clipboard":true}
,"sound-card":true
,"allow-network-access":true
,"basic-common-permissions":true}
```

Here is an overview of the permissions that I just set:

```
"gui": Allows Firefox to display windows to X11 securely using the XPRA X11 bridge
"sound-card": Allows Firefox to communicate with your sound card
"allow-network-access": Allows Firefox to access the network
"basic-common-permissions": Allows Firefox to do some basic things like save settings to it's own specially contained home directory, see the LOCAL and timezone ect.
```

It does NOT however, allow Firefox to access any files outside of it's own subuser. You could add a user-dirs permission to allow it to access the Downloads directory, for example, if you wished.

Once you have created a permissions.json file, you can go on to create a SubuserImagefile.

The docker-image/SubuserImagefile should look just like a Dockerfile:

FROM ubuntu
RUN `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -yq firefox`

Now you are done setting up your subuser image.

You can create a firefox subuser by running:

```
$ subuser subuser add firefox firefox@/home/student/my-subuser-images
```

You can run the firefox subuser by running:

```
$ subuser run firefox
```

You can create more than one firefox subuser. This is useful, if you want to have more than one Facebook account or Google account and not have to log out/in all the time. It is also usefull if you want to reduce the risk of cross-site scripting when you do internet banking.

subuser subuser add internet-banking firefox@/home/student/my-subuser-images

You can run your internet-banking subuser with the command

subuser run internet-banking

You can access a subuser's home directory by visiting ~/.subuser/homes.

You can share your subuser images with others, to reduce the burden of sandboxing applications for everybody. If you want to share your Firefox image, you can cd to my-subuser-images and turn that folder into a git repository:

```
$ cd ~/my-subuser-images
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Add Firefox image"
```

If you then push this git repo somewhere, then others can install your Firefox image easilly with the command:

$ subuser subuser add firefox firefox@http://example.com/student/my-subuser-images.git

They would run that subuser in the same way as if they had done the setup locally.

Comment: we tried this. firefox does open..but when i mention user-dirs : ["Downloads"]  in permission.Json,   it does not restrict the access to the only download folders as shown in the following video.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZrs8KngN68

Comment: So first part of question is resolved? Now you need to restrict access to "Downloads' folder only?

Comment: Yes. Do you have any solution to do that?

Comment: Please raise it as another question, and mark this as solved. As that a broader question with different scope.